# Hive external table with wild card

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to create an external Hive table with Location as wild card. Expecting that it will able to traverse the sub directory. But somehow it does not work and instead it create a directory with wild to target location.

Location I am specifying as   `/hadfsfolder1/hdfsfolder2/weblog/2013/*`

No data get exposed to external table, also is there any way to prevent the `*` directory creation , this cause a lot on inconvenience in terms of cleanup and restoring the directory back.

Comment: A recent patch has been added to Hadoop which will definitely handle this issue. See: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-3193 Which Hadoop/Hive version do you use?

Comment: Thanks for the link, will check it out..